# How to sum aggregate matrix rows in the following way?

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum, aggregate, unique

I have a matrix of size **n-by-3**. For some rows of this matrix, the first two columns are identical. I need to keep only one copy of these first-two-element combinations, where the third column will have the sum of 3<sup>rd</sup> column from rows with identical first-two-columns.

Here's an example of what I want to do:

```
M = [...
1 2 1
1 2 3
1 2 2
1 2 4
2 3 1
2 3 4
2 3 0];
```

The final matrix that I need is

```
R = [...
1 2 1+3+2+4
2 3 1+4+0];
```

How can this be done? I don't see how I can use the `unique` command for this.

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using? Why can't you use `unique`?

Comment: I use MATLAB 2016a. Because it works just for those matrices that whole rows are duplicated. not just some parts of rows. Do you think I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `unique` in combination with `accumarray`. Let's call the initial n x 3 array `A`:

```
[C, ~, ic] = unique(A(:,1:2), 'rows');
B = [C, accumarray(ic, A(:,3))];
```

Explanation:

`unique` outputs not only unique elements of array (rows in our case thanks to the argument `rows`), but also two arrays of indexes. The first one is the indexes of the first unique elements in `A`; I discard it since I don't use it. The second one can be used to reconstruct original array from the output array: `A(:, 1:2) = C(ic,:)`.

`accumarray` is the generalization of histogram computation, it makes the sum of elements in 2nd argument array for each unique index in the first argument array. In your case, you make the sum over the 3rd column of the original array only.

And that's all in two simple commands!